# Nested Switch with DialogInterface

Tags: java, android

i'm making a narrative game with multiple choices, so I have to work with nested switch.

I'm using a dialogInterface with a single choice and i would like to do something like that:

```
switch(i){
case 0: response1;
           switch(i){ 
                     case 0: response 2
                    switch(i){
                                case 0: response 3
                              }
                      }
}
```

But the problem is the switch key (i) , i dont know how to change it after the first switch :/

Here is my code:

```
listChoices = new String[]{"Answer1,answer2,answer3"};

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChoice);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Text to choose

            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(ChapTest.this);
            mBuilder.setTitle("Your choice:");

            mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listChoices, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int i) {
                //fonction list text
                    userInput.setText(listChoices[i]);

                          // Fonction message
                            ResponseMessage message = new ResponseMessage(userInput.getText().toString(), 1);
                            responseMessageList.add(message);


                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            ResponseMessage message2 = new ResponseMessage("Désolé " + prenom + ", tu tiens le coup?", 2);
                            responseMessageList.add(message2);

                            listChoices = new String[]{"answer4,answer5,answer6 "};

                            switch (i) {
                                case 0:
                                    ResponseMessage message6 = new ResponseMessage("Test", 2);
                                    responseMessageList.add(message6);
                                    break;
                            }

                            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you never reassign "i" variable after the second "list Choices = new...", so doing a "switch(i)" there it's absolutely useless because you're in the previous "case 0:..." of "i", so that variable remains constant for all that Case.

If you know how many deep it would be the "stack" of nested things you could just use different variables name other than "i" like "j", "k", etc...

```
listChoices = new.... 
mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listChoices, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
       ...use "i"...
       list Choices = new...
       mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listChoices, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int j) {
     ...use "j"... 
  } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            ResponseMessage message2 = new ResponseMessage("Désolé " + prenom + ", tu tiens le coup?", 2);
                            responseMessageList.add(message2);

                            listChoices = new String[]{"Non j'ai pas envie de le perdre", "J'ai envie qu'il revienne Papa "};

                            mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listChoices, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int j) {

                            switch (i) {
                                case 0:
                                    ResponseMessage message6 = new ResponseMessage("Test", 2);
                                    responseMessageList.add(message6);
                                    break;
                            }
}
```

Something like that?